# Как избежать подсчёт значения NaN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

```
data_wm_1 = data[(data['Pclass'] == '1') & (data['Sex'] == 'female')]
data_wm_2 = data[(data['Pclass'] == '2') & (data['Sex'] == 'female')]
data_wm_3 = data[(data['Pclass'] == '3') & (data['Sex'] == 'female')]
data_m_1 = data[(data['Pclass'] == '1') & (data['Sex'] == 'male')]
data_m_2 = data[(data['Pclass'] == '2') & (data['Sex'] == 'male')]
data_m_3 = data[(data['Pclass'] == '3') & (data['Sex'] == 'male')]


print(data_m_1['Age'].mean())
print(data_m_2['Age'].mean())
print(data_m_3['Age'].mean())
print(data_wm_1['Age'].mean())
print(data_wm_2['Age'].mean())
print(data_wm_3['Age'].mean())
```

Результат:

> ```
> nan
> nan
> nan
> nan
> nan
> nan
> ```

Это происходит из-за того, что в некоторых столбцах присутствуют значения `NaN`. И у меня вопрос - как избежать подсчёт этого значения, то есть считать все значения кроме nan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas достаточно умный, чтобы не учитывать `NaN` при расчете среднего значения.

Пример:

```
In [199]: pd.Series([1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan]).mean()
Out[199]: 2.0

In [200]: pd.Series([1,2,3]).mean()
Out[200]: 2.0
```

То что вы пытаетесь сделать можно сделать элегантнее:

```
In [205]: data = pd.read_csv(r'D:\work\.data\titanic\train.csv')

In [206]: data.groupby(['Pclass', 'Sex'], as_index=False)[['Age']].mean()
Out[206]:
   Pclass     Sex        Age
0       1  female  34.611765
1       1    male  41.281386
2       2  female  28.722973
3       2    male  30.740707
4       3  female  21.750000
5       3    male  26.507589
```

PS на будущее советую всегда [приводить примеры входных и выходных данных в вопросах по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / Machine Learning / etc.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно возьму на заметку)